# What is the use of Docker in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I am new learner for Spring Boot. I have refer some YouTube channel for learning myself. But in Udemy course only there has using Docker itself. No YouTube channel using Docker.
Can I able to create a Spring Boot application without using Docker?
Is Docker important to develop an Application in Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring Boot can be used without Docker; it's absolutely not required to use Docker. The reasons why Docker was used, is probably because the author finds it handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can use spring without docker. To do this, just install java on your computer.

Usually, docker is used in order to be able to work with other resources, such as a database, rabbitmq, etc.

Docker makes it easy for you to interact with external resources, but it's not required.

Comment: No, Docker is not for using a Database or message broker. Matter of fact, Docker is relatively poor at such stateful applications. For Spring's purposes, Docker is for (typically) deploying and scaling the application according to 12 factor principles

Comment: @OneCricketeer Without going into the details of industrial application development using 12 factors, it is much easier for me to quickly raise any database or message broker or something else in a docker container, and then delete it or declare it in docker-compose for later use.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is another concept. You can learn spring boot independently. The concept of containerization brings in the docker.

Docker is basically an application that facilitates containerization. In order to learn spring boot you don't need docker. Docker can be used with any application, you will have to create containers and then create/use applications inside the docker.

Learn spring boot first, have some grip on it and then proceed towards the concept of containerization.